# Javascript Regex split (val(number)=)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This is my data

var result= Val1=08182014&sydney-holistic-dental-centre-14750975&2000&Dentist&
    Val2=08182014&nine-dragons-restaurant-12494711&2000&Restaurant&
    Val3=08182014&mr-switch-electrical-14251034&2000&Electricians&
    Val4=08182014&laser-sight-13604978&2000&Doctors&
    Val5=08182014&lube-mobile-the-mobile-mechanics-14755685&2000&Mechanics&
    Val6=08182014&mr-h2o-plumbing-services-14223825&2000&Plumbers&
    Val7=08182014&philippe-xavier-hairdressers-14887853&2000&Hairdressers&
    Val8=08182014&gerard-malouf-partners-12372365&2000&Solicitors&
    Val9=08182014&beauty-grace-13817412&2000&Beauty_Salons&
    Val10=08182014&rapid-construction-pty-ltd-15093518&2000&Builders

I want to parse my data and format is `<date>&<business>&<post_code>&<category>`. I want to skip val1,val2 etc and just to get 08182014&sydney-holistic-dental-centre-14750975&2000&Dentist which is `<date>&<business>&<post_code>&<category>`. What should i do to skip Val1=,val2-,val3= etc and put in the array. After that i can loop through my array and split it by (&).

i want to make an array like (08182014&sydney-holistic-dental-centre-14750975&2000&Dentist, 08182014&nine-dragons-restaurant-12494711&2000&Restaurant , etc)

Comment: String split on /Val\d+=/

Comment: @Satpal no need for `&` before Val.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can `.split(/&Val\d+=/)` to split string in array. using `&` You can simply use [`.replace(regexp)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), Then

```
var arr = str.split(/&Val\d+=/); //split
for(var i=0; i< arr.length -1; i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/Val\d+=/g, '');  //replace Val1, Val2 string
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4YTCL/)

Comment: but i want to put each line into an array but if i remove val= then how will i make an array like (08182014&sydney-holistic-dental-centre-14750975&2000&Dentist, 08182014&nine-dragons-restaurant-12494711&2000&Restaurant , etc)

Comment: @user3754380, Updated answer. I have use `console.log` in demo

Answer (score 0):

### Capture to Group 1

Use this:

```
var the_matches = []; 
var myregex = /^Val\d+=(.*)/mg;
var thematch = myregex.exec(yourString);
while (thematch != null) {
    the_matches.push(thematch[1]);
    thematch = myregex.exec(yourString);
}
```

Your array of matches is `the_matches`.

**Explanation**

- The `m` flag turns on multi-line mode, allowing `^` to match on each line
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `Val` matches `Val` (but it will not be in the array)
- `\d+` matches the digits
- `=` matches `=`
- `(.*)` captures everything after the `=` up to the end of the line to Group 1
- the code builds an array with all the Group 1 captures

Comment: but i want to put each line into an array but if i remove val= then how will i make an array like (08182014&sydney-holistic-dental-centre-14750975&2000&Dentist, 08182014&nine-dragons-restaurant-12494711&2000&Restaurant , etc)...

Comment: Run the code I gave you. The `the_matches` array has the values you want.